# Make a certain layer always appear on top of all the other layers?

Tags: wms

I'm finding a lot of material written about how to order features within the same layer, but I can't find anything about how to order the layers themselves in a WMS request. Please note that this is specifically about WMS.

Answer (score 4):

Rendering order of layers is documented in the WMS standard.

> The mandatory LAYERS parameter lists the map layer(s) to be returned
>   by this GetMap request. The value of the LAYERS parameter is a
>   comma-separated list of one or more valid layer names. Allowed layer
>   names are the character data content of any  element in
>   the service metadata. A WMS shall render the requested layers by
>   drawing the leftmost in the list bottommost, the next one over that,
>   and so on.

You can make the layer to be on top by requesting it last in the LAYERS=& parameter of GetMap. The WMS standard does not offer a method for a fixed predefined layer order so that you could for example force buildings to be rendered on top of landuse. If client asks LAYERS=buildings,landuse& then the server must render buildings below the landuse.

WMS servers may have their own non-standard implementations for use cases like forcing the copyright texts to show always on top.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to set up a layer group, with the desired layer on top.

Comment: Please edit and expand on your answer - how will this specifically help with a WMS request?

Comment: Layer group will make order of the layers independent from the request. However if there are other layers at the client, there is nothing to do for making the requested wms to stay at top.